# Is there a simple way to ensure that fields within a contact form are present and/or valid (preferably present)?

Tags: php, html

I am a not very good with php forms and need help with the one I am working on.  First and foremost I would like help with a simple way to ensure that all fields are present and valid.  For the sake of space, I am using a form similar to this 
link http://distancebrothers.com/request-quote.html

The php code is listed below:

```
<?php

 .
 .
 .
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$cmpny = $_POST['cmpny'];
$street = $_POST['street'];
$city_st_zip = $_POST['city_st_zip'];
$respond = $_POST['respond'];
$num_passengers = $_POST['num_passengers']; 
$trip_type = $_POST['trip_type'];   
$num_pickups = $_POST['num_pickups'];   
$bus_size = $_POST['bus_size'];
$pickup_name = $_POST['pickup_name'];       
$pickup_street_name = $_POST['pickup_street_name']; 
$pickup_city_st_zip = $_POST['pickup_city_st_zip'];
$depart_date = $_POST['depart_date'];
$depart_time = $_POST['depart_time'];
$dropoff_name = $_POST['dropoff_name'];
$dropoff_street_name = $_POST['dropoff_street_name'];
$dropoff_city_st_zip = $_POST['dropoff_city_st_zip'];
$dropoff_date = $_POST['dropoff_date']; 
$dropoff_time = $_POST['dropoff_time'];
$spec_instr = $_POST['spec_instr'];
$meet_greet = $_POST['meet_greet'];
$ada = $_POST['ada'];
$extra = $_POST['extra'];
$find_us = $_POST['find_us'];
$formcontent="<html> <body><b>Contact Information:</b>  <br><br>Name: $name 
<br>Email: $email <br>Phone: $phone <br>Company / Group Name: $cmpny 
<br>Street Name: $street <br>City, State, Zip Code: $city_st_zip <br>Respond 
Via:  $respond <br><br><b>Event / Trip Details:</b> <br><br>Number of 
Passengers:  $num_passengers <br>Trip Type:  $trip_type <br>Number of 
Pickups:  $num_pickups <br>Bus Size:  $bus_size <br><br><b>Event / Trip 
Times - Departure and Destination:<br>Pick up location</b>  <br><br>Name:  
$pickup_name <br>Street Name:  $pickup_street_name <br>City, State, Zip 
Code:  $pickup_city_st_zip <br>Depart Date:  $depart_date <br>Depart Time:  
$depart_time <br><br><b>Drop Off Location</b><br><br>Name:  $dropoff_name 
<br>Street Name:  $dropoff_street_name <br>City, State, Zip Code:  
$dropoff_city_st_zip <br>Return Date:  $dropoff_date <br>Return Time:  
$dropoff_time <br><br><b>Contact Information:</b>  <br><br>Itinerary / 
Special Instructions / Additional Info:<br>$spec_instr <br>Airport Meet & 
Greet:  $meet_greet <br>ADA Accessible Coach:  $ada <br>Extra Storage:  
$extra <br>How did you find us?  $find_us </body> </html>";
$recipient = "distancebrothers.com,jldouglas58@gmail.com";
$subject = "Request for a Quote";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header( 'Location: http://www.distancebrothers.com/quote-confirmation.html') 
;?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by valid?

Comment: I meant to say validate.  I guess it does not matter if, say an address is valid.  They will have to be notified to validate all the info and to confirm anyway.  Thanks for your reply.  Can you help?

Comment: What I meant is... Does the user have to validate the answers he supplied OR Does the actual information need to be validated?  As in checking if an email is in the proper form, of if a link has http.... that type of validation.

Comment: I just want to ensure that no fields are left blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
$valid = 1;    
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
  {
   echo "$key=$value";
     if ($value=="" || $value===null)
           { $valid = 0; }
  }
```

You should probably trim the variables or white spaces, just in case a user tries to get around a required field. trim($value)

Comment: I know very little about.  But I am learning as I go. All the contact forms I have used in php I have downloaded from somewhere or another.  Where exactly do I place this piece of code.  Also the trim($value).  Not sure what to do with that.  Thanks.